# Displaying the Drupal administration interface in the main content area

Tags: 7

How would I go about displaying the Drupal administration interface in the main content area, instead of it taking up the whole page when the overlay module is disabled...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are using the Drupal core *Seven* theme as the administration theme, and you would like to use the active theme instead.

You can change this by going to `Appearance`. At the bottom of that page you have a select for `Administration theme`. Choose `Default theme` to use your site's active theme as the admin theme.